# How to calculating physical quantity by calculating the difference between IN and OUT

Tags: mysql, sql, database, join, innodb

I'm developing an inventory control application using and I'm using MySQL RDBMS with InnoDB engine ,currently I want to generate a report that calculate the physical quantity for the products by calculating the difference between the SUM of the IN_OUT column using a MySQL query.

I'm using the value "1" in the in_out_products as IN and "0" as OUT

so I need a column that has the difference between IN and OUT 
 **IN - OUT =Physical quantity** for each product 
in more clear way I mean the difference between SUM(quantity) where in_out=1 and SUM(quantity) where in_out=0 ,in_out column is in the in_out_products table

first table

```
select * from products;


+------------+--------------+-------------+----------------+-------+------------+
| product_id | product_code | part_number | product_name   | brand | location   |
+------------+--------------+-------------+----------------+-------+------------+
|          1 | 100100       | 100200      | RICHO maginate | RICHO | location 4 |
|          2 | 1112211      | 100300      | RICHO Cyan     | RICHO | location 4 |
|          3 | 111333       | 100400      | RICHO Yellow   | RICHO | location 4 |
+------------+--------------+-------------+----------------+-------+------------+
```

second table

```
+-----------+------------+--------------+-------------+----------+--------+
| record_id | product_id | product_code | part_number | quantity | in_out |
+-----------+------------+--------------+-------------+----------+--------+
|         1 |          1 | 100100       | 100200      |       10 |      1 |
|         2 |          1 | 100100       | 100200      |       10 |      1 |
|         3 |          1 | 100100       | 100200      |       30 |      1 |
|         4 |          2 | 1112211      | 100300      |       10 |      1 |
|         5 |          2 | 1112211      | 100300      |       10 |      1 |
|         6 |          2 | 1112211      | 100300      |       10 |      1 |
|         7 |          2 | 1112211      | 100300      |       10 |      1 |
|         8 |          3 | 111333       | 100400      |       10 |      1 |
|         9 |          3 | 111333       | 100400      |       10 |      1 |
|        10 |          3 | 111333       | 100400      |       10 |      1 |
+-----------+------------+--------------+-------------+----------+--------+
```

now I want to create a SQL query that display all the products with there current quantity ,I didn't managed that,so far I managed to get the IN quantity with this query .

SQL query calculating IN quantity for each product:

```
select p.product_id,
       p.product_id,
       p.product_code,
       p.product_name,
       SUM(io.quantity) as physical_quantity
       from products as p,
       in_out_products as io where p.product_id=io.product_id and io.deleted_at is null and in_out=1 group by p.product_id;
```

result

`+------------+------------+--------------+----------------+-------------------+
| product_id | product_id | product_code | product_name   | physical_quantity |
+------------+------------+--------------+----------------+-------------------+
|          1 |          1 | 100100       | RICHO maginate |                50 |
|          2 |          2 | 1112211      | RICHO Cyan     |                40 |
|          3 |          3 | 111333       | RICHO Yellow   |                30 |
+------------+------------+--------------+----------------+-------------------+`

Comment: What do you mean by **display all the products with there current quantity**. Can you add expected output

Comment: what I mean I want to get the difference between SUM(quantity) where in_out=1 and SUM(quantity) where in_out=0 ,this column in the in_out_products table

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If am not wrong you need to use `Conditional Aggregate`

```
select p.product_id,
       p.product_id,
       p.product_code,
       p.product_name,
       SUM(io.quantity) as physical_quantity,
       SUM(case when in_out=1 then io.quantity else 0 END) - 
       SUM(case when in_out=0 then io.quantity else 0 END) AS Difference
from products as p 
Join in_out_products as io 
on p.product_id=io.product_id 
Where io.deleted_at is null 
and in_out=1 
group by p.product_id;
```

Comment: thanks for your answer but I'm getting a syntax  error `You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right 
syntax to use near 'SUM(case when in_out=1 then io.quantity else 0 END) - SUM(case when in_o' at line 6 0.013 sec`